# Leaflet | Javascript automatic ColorCircles for each ID in JSON-Object

Tags: javascript, json, object, leaflet

Please forgive me, this is my first question after searching a lot for it here.

I am trying to automatically select different color circles on a leaflet map for an attribute in an object.

The ID has different values in the database, so unfortunately I can't assign it to fixed colors.

The JSON object I am working with looks like this:

`fcoord = { id: "xxxxxxxx", lat: "xxxxxx", lon: "xxxxxx" }`

The thing is that for every different ID in the Object it should automatic mark a Circle on the map in a different Color.

My JavaScript Code looks like this:

```
var fMarkers = newSet([]);
        for (var i:0;i<fcoord.length;i++) {
        drawCirclef(fcoord[i], mymap, fMarkers);
        }

function drawCirclef(fcoord, map, fMarkers){
    var circle = L.circle(fcoord.lat, fcoord.lon] {
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
            radius: 1500,
            fillColor: 'green',
    }).addTo(map)
    fMarkers.add(circle);
```

The result is that every ID in the object is highlighted in the same color because I have defined it as 'green'.

I'm stuck on how to make it mark in a different color for each ID.

Can someone please help me move forward or find a solution.

Many many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that retuns the wanted color for the id

```
function getColor(id){
   switch(id){
      case 'id1': return 'green';
      case 'id2': return 'blue';
      default: return 'red';
   }

}

var fMarkers = newSet([]);
for (var i:0;i<fcoord.length;i++) {
   drawCirclef(fcoord[i], mymap, fMarkers);
}

function drawCirclef(fcoord, map, fMarkers){
    var circle = L.circle(fcoord.lat, fcoord.lon] {
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
            radius: 1500,
            fillColor: getColor(fcoord.id),
   }).addTo(map)
   fMarkers.add(circle);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if I explicitly know the ID's and assign them to a specific color.

It is a good approach, maybe I can build on it.

Comment: you need something to know which color you want to use ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround with a friend of mine:

First creating a var for the Colors of the future Circles:

```
var colors = ['cyan', 'grey', 'pink', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange']
var colorsForKey = {}
```

Edit the JSON-Object so that each ID will be a Key with all appearing Lat, Lon etc. inside it.

Creating a Counter which walks through the Var and everytime a new ID appears, jump to the next Color.

```
function createColors(fcoord){
    counter = 0;
    for (i in fcoord) {
            counter = 0
            colorsForKey[i] = colors[counter];
            counter = counter + 1
            }
    }

function getColor(id) {
    return colorsForKey[ID];
    }

function drawCirclef(fcoord, map, fMarkers, ID){
    var circle = L.circle([fcoord.lat, fcoord.lon] {
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        radius: 1500,
        fillColor: getColor(ID),
        color: getColor(ID)
    }.addTo(map)
    .fMarkers.add(circle);
}

var fMarkers = newSet([]);
createColors(fcoord);
for (var ID in fcoord){
    for (var i=0;<fcoord[ID].length;i++){
        drawCirclef(fcoord[ID][i], mymap, fMarkers, ID);
```